# QWebView, using an HTTP proxy for video tag

Tags: qt, video, proxy, qwebview

I have the following problem with QT 5.1.1 QWebView under Windows,
If I load an HTML page containing a  tag, QWebView renders the video correctly.
If I set a proxy using

> QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);

the HTML page is served by the proxy but the video stream is requested directly to the original web server with user agent "Lavf/55.21.100".
I tried setting the proxy in Windows Media Player, but the behavior is the same (while WMP works using the proxy I set).
I don't know where to set the proxy for QT
Thank you
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was setting the http_proxy environment variable